Single word for 'listening history'
I am beginning a software project to track one's listening history—that is, a record or timeline of the auditory media one has listened to. See last.fm for an example of an existing service that tracks and provides statistics on one's listening history. For concise variable names and discussion, I want a one-word noun that encapsulates this notion of listening history.
If there is no existing word with this definition, I would like a word that connotes this meaning by its construction. For example, "audiograph" and "audiography" come to mind. Does one or the other more precisely connote the desired meaning? (Is there a consistent difference in usage between -graph and -graphy?) Other possibilities might include "phonograph" and "sonography" except these terms have sufficiently well-known existing definitions that using them for my purposes would be confusing. I also don't know if there are other "sound" or "record" morphemes I am unaware of or whose meanings are closer to my specific intent.
The best word would be the one that most effectively connotes the definition of "listening history" given above in bold while being the least likely to be confused with another concept.
Example Usage
If I had been keeping a(n) _________ back then, I would be able to tell you which song I listened to the most two years ago.
I signed up recently, so only the last five months of my _________ are saved on last.fm.

I’m voting to close this question because naming things in software is, per our policies, considered off-topic for this site.

You're right. My apologies for failing to read the on-topic policies before posting. Is there any action I should take at this point (i.e., should I delete the question, or allow it to be voted on and closed that way?)

Alternatively, since I am also interested in using the desired single-word not merely as a variable name etc. but also in regular text and conversation (albeit most likely text or conversation revolving around such software), is it possible that I could edit the question to be more on-topic?

You may use neologisms based on 2 greek roots such as phonochrony or  otochrony.

There's a question on a single word for a list of books someone's read with no good answer. And historically people have written a lot more about reading than listening.

This question, at its core, still seems too much like a question about naming a variable because you're putting unnatural constraints on what expressions you'll accept (i.e., that it has to be a single word or nonce word). See my Meta writeup. Also, both "example" sentences arguably have enough context for generic words to be extremely apt, such as "a record" or "track" (no article) in the first sentence.

Spotify just uses "listening history". Perhaps you're overthinking it. Having slightly longer variable names can be a bit annoying, but it is more clear to other developers looking at your code.

The word for tracking one's listening history, i.e. a record or timeline of what and when one listened to auditory media (usually music) is the word scrobble. While associated initially with last.fm it seems to have evolved beyond that specific usage, see the third entry below in particular.
This Showtime definition does refer to last.fm:

What is a scrobble and what is scrobbling? Your scrobbles are a record
of your entire listening history - not just on Last.fm, but
everywhere. You could think of Last.fm like a digital record
collection, except that it's not just tracking the music you own, but
the music you've listened to -- including on streaming services like
Spotify and Apple Music.
However, a scrobble is more than just a count of how many times you've
listened to a track, but also a record of when.

The relevant Wiktionary definition of scrobble is Etymology 2:

(Internet slang) To publish one's media consumption habits to the
Internet via software, in order to track when and how often certain
items are played.

Wikipedia further informs that scrobbling pre- and post-dates last.fm, emphasis mine:

Scrobbling is possible with music stored and played locally via
software on devices such as PCs, mobile phones, tablets, and
standalone (hardware) media players. Indeed, these were the only
methods of scrobbling listening data both before and after the
existence of the Last.fm radio service.

To respond to the usage example requested in the question, either sentence seems appropriate:

I signed up recently, so only the last five months of my scrobbles are saved on last.fm.
I signed up recently, so only my last five months of scrobbling is saved on last.fm.


The Wikipedia passage is a bit unclear, but gets the idea across. I'm not sure why Salesforce would have an entire page about scrobbling! It might not be Salesforce per se, but the CBS broadcast network's knowledge base which has Salesforce in the URL

There is no such word.
If I had been keeping a record back then, I would be able to tell you which song I listened to the most two years ago.
I signed up recently, so only the last five months of my listening history are saved on last.fm.
